# Why can you only use defer when src is specified?

Tags: javascript, html

When validating code that uses the `<script>` tag I get the following warning on validator.w3.org

> Element script must not have attribute
>   defer unless attribute src is also
>   specified.

I don't understand the need for this, could someone explain it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The point of defer is to say "You can keep on parsing the HTML before waiting for the script to arrive".

If the script is right there in the HTML, then you can't (since the script is in the way in the source code) and it would be pointless (since there is no external dependancy that would block parsing).

Comment: Ahh that makes sense, I thought defer meant to not look at the script between the tags until the rest of the page as loaded.

Comment: I guess the issue here is if you're loading an external resource (e.g. jquery), then using code referencing that script from an inline script.  You can get around that by moving your script into a separate file to the HTML code, but it's not ideal / would be helpful if you could somehow define dependencies between your script tags, or defer all to ensure they're loaded in order regardless of where the code's held... Do you know of any better solution than simply moving all dependant code to external resources?

Answer (score 2):

`Defer` attribute means asyncronous script loading (by default scripts are loaded by browser in first turn, and are executed immedialtely after loading completed).

Without `src` property there will be nothing to load, and nothing to defer.